# DIV background extend behind another DIV

Tags: html, position, extend

First time asking a question :)

My header DIV has a background that is curved like a wave. I have a sidebar floated to the right located in a DIV underneath the header DIV. The background image for header curves up right where sidebar is which leaves a gap where sidebar hits the bottom of the header div (because obviously divs aren't curved). I need the background of sidebar to extend underneath header so there is no gap. What should I do?

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body>
<div id="main-content"></div>
<div id="side-bar></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:272px;
margin:0 auto;
background-image:url('../img/header.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
#body{
width:960px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
padding-bottom:159px;
```

}

```
#main-content{
width:60%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
padding:15px;
background-color:#fbf8ee;
```

}

```
#side-bar{
width:30%;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
float:right;
padding:10px;
background-color:#961912;
    border-right:thick #558c21 solid;
    border-left:thick #558c21 solid;
```

}

![Here is a screenshot of what it looks like currently. The sidebar has no content so it is narrow but I want it to extend up behind the header image so there is no gap.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYSnY.jpg)

Comment: can you provide a css and html code?

Comment: I tried to add it but it said I wasn't formatting it properly. I will see what I can do...

Comment: for line with code use four spaces

Comment: Can you include the full link to the image, I'm having a hard time getting the full picture of what you're wanting done in my head.  Also, in the example code you left out a closing " in <div id="body> and <div id="side-bar>.

Comment: Oops, I was rushing. I wrote it in instead of copying and pasting from my code.

I will give you a screen shot of what I'm seeing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure on what you're wanting to achieve, but if you're wanting the sidebar to show behind the header and extend upwards, try adding to the sidebar style:

```
margin-top: -100px; /* Higher or lower number depending on how far up you want it to go */
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
```

Comment: This worked! I tried the margin-top but couldnt' figure out how to get it behind the header DIV. I figured it probably could've been done with z-index. Thanks! Still learning :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. :) If you don't mind, can you click "Accept Answer" when you have a chance? And welcome to StackOverflow, I'm somewhat new as well.

Comment: Okay so I ran into a problem with the negative z-index...my links won't work :/ They will only work if I take out the z-index. Any suggestions? (The links I put in the sidebar)

Comment: One thing you can try is setting the header to a z-index of 2, and then the sidebar to a z-index of 1.  Sometimes having a negative z-index can affect how the links work.  Another idea, if the links are below the header, is to create a new div for the links themselves, and give it a higher z-index than the header.  Lastly, you can also try setting the .div a (link class) to a higher z-index than the header.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand you correctly but try to add:

```
position: relative;
top: -10px;
```

to #side-bar as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/NpZJV/

If I may advice, don't use % for width/height and positions use px instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could use CSS3 to make a background size, check it out to see if it solves your problem. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp 
Try using

```
background-size: 600px 2921px;
```

You might be able to get it to fit

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: background-size still works..
I only provided the link so she could test it out over there.